# Trying to choose any non-disabled option from a select element

Tags: select, css-selectors, automated-tests, cypress

I have a parent record with multiple child records, all shown together on the ViewParentWithChildren and EditParentWithChildren screens.  I want to write a cypress test that adds a new child record to an existing parent record. Each child record is in a `<tr>` of course.

The problem is, the `<select>` element has many `<option disabled>` invalid options in it. I need to select a valid, enabled one, and I don't know ahead of time what the names/values in that option are going to be.  I don't care what they are, I just need to select any non-disabled option.

I try a standard-ish:

```js
cy.contains('button', /Add Another Child Record/i).click();
cy.get('[name=child_id_name][value=""]')  // newly added has nothing in the required field
      .parents('tr')
      .within(tr => {
        cy.get('input[name=child_id_name]').type(randomAlpha());
        cy.get('input[name=description]').type(randomAlpha());
        cy.get('select[name=type]').select(?????);  // TODO
      });
```

Cypress only allows selecting an `<option>` via name, value, or index. Attempting to `.select` a valid `<option>` directly doesn't work, by design.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of other ways you may or may not find easier

**Example page for POC**

```html
<select>
  <option value="1" disabled>three</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

**Method 1: Expose the `<select>` first**

```js
cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', '2')  // by default the selected value is the first enabled
  .then($select => {
    cy.wrap($select)
      .find('option:enabled:last')
      .then($lastEnabledOption => {
        cy.wrap($select).select($lastEnabledOption.val())
      })
  })
  .should('have.value', '4')  // check new value
```

**Method 2: Set the selected attribute with jQuery**

```js
cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', '2')          // initial value
  .find('option:enabled:last')
  .invoke('attr', 'selected', true)

cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', '4')          // new value
```

Comment: Nice!  Can you also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392233/cypress-deleting-a-sub-row-while-trapped-inside-within-and-then

Answer (score 0):

The solution was kind of inside-out. Get all non-disabled options from that select first, then go `within` one of them, and "escape hatch" back out again to the select, feeding the `.text()` to the `.select`

```js
cy.contains('button', /Add Another Child Record/i).click();
cy.get('[name=child_id_name][value=""]')  // newly added has nothing in the required field
      .parents('tr')
      .within(tr => {
        cy.get('input[name=child_id_name]').type(randomAlpha());
        cy.get('input[name=description]').type(randomAlpha());
        cy.get('select[name=type] option:not([disabled])') // get all its non-disabled options
          .last() // the first option is usually blank for un-selecting, so, .last
          .within(option => {
            cy.root().closest('select').select(option.text());
          });
      });
```