# cypress - deleting a sub-row while trapped inside .within and .then

Tags: cypress

I have a EditParentAndChildren screen where I want a test that:

1. navigates to page
2. remembers the name of the parent
3. pick one of the children rows
4. remember its id/name
5. delete it via the Trashcan button on that row
6. save
7. navigate to a View
8. ensure the parent's name appears and the deleted child's name does not

I can't seem to pluck text off of the screen and put it into one of Cypress's @alias variables, and standard js variables aren't allowed by cypress. So, I use `.then` to get the value that way.

But when I choose a child row and go `.within` to get its name and click its delete button, I can't then issue the final assertions for the test because I'm still in the `.within`, I can't escape the `.within` because the `.then` for getting the child's name is completely inside, and, trying to `.root().closest()` doesn't work because the `<tr>` I'm in is not only getting deleted but I'm doing a page nav afterward.

```js
    cy.get('[name=parentname]')
      .invoke('val')
      .then(parentName => {

        cy.get('[class^=childrenTable]')
          .find('[name=child_id]')
          .first()
          .parents('tr')
          .within(tr => {
            cy.get('[name=child_id]')
              .invoke('val')
              .then(nameOfchildToDelete => {

                // delete this child
                cy.get('[class*=trash]').click();
                cy.get(loadingSpinner).should('not.exist');

                // ERROR can't find submit button, you are still .within the <tr>
                cy.contains(/Submit/i).click();

                cy.url().should('match', /parent\/\d+$/);
                cy.get(loadingSpinner).should('not.exist');
                cy.contains('[class*=breadcrumb_currentcrumb]', parentName).should('exist');
                cy.contains('table', nameOfChildToDelete).should('not.exist');
              });
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is simply never to use `.within`. Formerly I was selecting the row, then within it selecting & using each piece of the row.  Instead, select each piece of a row using the same selector that selects that row.

Not this:

```js
cy.get('[class^=childrenTable]')
          .find('[name=child_id]')
          .first()
          .parents('tr')
          .within(tr => {
            cy.get('[name=child_id]')
              .invoke('val')
              .then(nameOfchildToDelete => {
```

More like this:

```js
cy.get('[class^=childrenTable] [name=sample_id]:first-child')
    .invoke('val')
    .then(nameOfSampleToDelete => {
        // etc...

        cy.get('[class^=childrenTable] [class*=trash]').first().click();
```

Code inside a `.then` is just like outside the `.then` excepting the level of indent, so most of the code is the same.  But code inside a `.within` is kind of at a dead-end.  You can't return values from a `.within` and can't set state or js vars from the outer context.

So: don't use `.within`, always use long selectors, and don't worry about picking "sections" like a particular `<tr>` or a particular card in a FlexBox for re-use.

If the selectors are very long consider moving them to a `const` string outside of the file and possibly concatting them if need be. But generally in Cypress trying to enter into a context is something of an anti-pattern.